# Can Fabric breakdown usage by iPhone device type?

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I am trying to use http://fabric.io to see app usage by iPhone device type (iPhone 6s, iPhone 7 Plus, etc.). I can see general iOS daily active users broken down by device category (iPhone, iPad, iPod) but not device category subtype. I don't see a way to do this on the Fabric site. Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. For events in the analytics section of your dashboard, this is not possible at the moment. For the Crashlytics section, there is a device filter per specific device.

Comment: Is there any plan to add that in the future?

Comment: It's not on our immediate roadmap for Fabric. I believe you can get the information in Google Analytics if you link Fabric and Firebase together.